# Highlight xml code in textarea on my html website using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web

I'm building a website which has a textarea where it displays a chunk of XML code and allows user to edit it. It will be like below:

```
<textarea>
  <person>
    <name>AAA</name>
    <position>Manager</position>
    <age>40</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>BBB</name>
    <position>CEO</position>
    <age>50</age>
  </person>
</textarea>
```

So basically the user will see a text box with the below XML code that he can edit:

```
  <person>
    <name>AAA</name>
    <position>Manager</position>
    <age>40</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>BBB</name>
    <position>CEO</position>
    <age>50</age>
  </person>
```

Of course by default they will show as plain, black text. My goal is to

1) Highlight the xml tags (same as what StackOverflow shows) so that it's easier for the user to read the xml content

2) When the user edits the xml content, the content is dynamically highlighted again

Is there any JavaScript that's ready out there and will help me do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off topic on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

There are some good JavaScript libraries out there that **highlights** codes in HTML pages. For example, you have [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/).

In your case, you could do something like :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@9.12.0/build/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@9.12.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>
<pre><code class="xml">
  <person>
    <name>AAA</name>
    <position>Manager</position>
    <age>40</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>BBB</name>
    <position>CEO</position>
    <age>50</age>
  </person>
</code></pre>
```

And you would have your code highlighted as XML. But this won't work in a textarea.

You may have to build your own program so that the users can edit the code. Something like :

1. You create an editable code box (**highlighted** by the above library)
2. The user clicks on the box to edit its content.
3. The user edits the code.
4. The user validates the changes.
5. You highlight your box again (on changes).

---

Hope that helps.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO.  Worse, the question is also off topic for asking for software suggestions and you shouldn't be answering it at all. Please delete this.